# Spinlocks running simultaneously

Tags: c, multithreading, locking

Suppose we have these global variables:

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
spinlock_t* lock;
```

And suppose we have these two threads running at the same time.

```
void thread1(void)
{
    y++;
    spin_lock(lock);
    x++;
    spin_unlock(lock):
}

void thread2(void)
{
    spin_lock(lock);
    x++;
    spin_unlock(lock);
    y++;
}
```

I get my result as `y=1` and `x=2` but I expect for both x and y to be equal to 2. Why is this occurring?

Comment: Why would it not?  Please explain in detail.

Comment: Unsynchronized non-atomic, non-readonly access to `y` in two threads -> undefined behavior.

Comment: I'm assuming you're not consistently getting the same result, but sometimes seeing 2,2 also?

Comment: It's an ersatz, pseudocode homework question - OP has not actually tried it.

Comment: ..and once every two billion times round, an increment of y would fail.  'I get my result as y=1 and x=2' is grossly misleading.

Comment: @MartinJames: Actually, that is an easy race window to hit. Your thread creation just has to run `thread2()` first, then schedule `thread1()` when `thread2()` unlocks the spin-lock. I can imagine a few reasons why this could happen.

Comment: @EOF there are two chances.  One of the y++ has to be interrupted or their execution has to be overlaid because both threads are running on different cores.  It's a one-shot deal - there is no loop in the thread function, seeking to demonstrate the issue.  It's not going to be lock that the problem shows up, (sorry:).

Comment: @MartinJames: Take a uniprocessor machine that doesn't have atomic-read-modify-write. On such a machine, atomicity is often implemented by disabling interrupts. So `thread2()` is running, disables interrupts in the lock, an interrupt is queued, interrupts are re-enabled in the unlock. Now, on some architectures the "enable interrupts" instruction delays enabling interrupts by one instruction. If `thread2()` uses that delay-slot for the load of `y`...

Comment: The issue is why you expected `y` to equal 2. That's the thing that doesn't make sense about your question. If you explain why you had this expectation, we can explain where you got things wrong.

Comment: What threading standard or library are you using? What *precisely* do the `spin_lock` and `spin_unlock` functions do? What memory visibility semantics do they have? You're going to be very bad answers that are terribly misleading if you don't include in the question all the assumptions you're expected to make.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: What kind of semantics could `spin_lock()/spin_unlock()` *possibly have* that would make concurrent execution of `thread1()` and `thread2()` non-racy?

Comment: @EOF They could have no defined memory visbility semantics, making the functions racy on `x` as well as `y`.

Comment: Are you actually getting the results of `y=1` and `x=2` on real hardware or is this a hypothetical where someone told you that you got those results? If the former, could you tell us what platform and what type of threads (POSIX, WIN32, etcetera)?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following order of execution:

1. thread 2 locks the lock
2. thread 2 reads from `x` into register A
3. thread 2 increments register A
4. thread 2 writes register A into `x`, it now contains `1`
5. thread 2 unlocks the lock
6. thread 2 reads from `y` into register A
7. thread 2 increments register A
8. thread 1 reads from `y` into register B
9. thread 2 writes register A to `y`, it now contains `1`
10. thread 1 increments register B
11. thread 1 writes register B to `y`, it now contains `1`
12. thread 1 locks the lock
13. thread 1 reads from `x` into register A
14. thread 1 increments register A
15. thread 1 writes register A to `x`, it now contains `2`
16. thread 1 unlocks the lock

Since there's no lock protecting access to `y`, the intermixed sequence of operations in steps 6 through 11 results in `y` only being incremented by `1` instead of `2`. This is why locking is needed when you have multiple threads modifying a non-atomic variable.

Incrementing `y` before the locked region in one thread and after the locked region in the other thread doesn't ensure mutual exclusion, because you can't be sure that thread 1 will try to run before thread 2.

Comment: You mean `y`? `x` is protected by the lock.

Comment: Ugh, I got them backwards in my answer!

Comment: Oh, not as bad as I thought, I got them right in the list of steps.

Comment: "*This is why locking is needed when you have multiple threads modifying a non-atomic variable.*" This doesn't make sense. Locking is needed if, and only if, the standard for whatever threading model the OP is using says it's needed. And if the standard says it's needed, that's why it's needed. The OP doesn't mention any particular platform or standard, so your claim that a lock is needed has no basis. He could be, for example, using a platform where all variables are volatile and all multithreading is cooperative. His CPU might not have registers and do all operations to memory.

Comment: I included a refutation of your answer in my answer.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz My answer is based on threading in general. If there are exceptions, they don't refute the general approach, which is that you have to perform your own mutual exclusion whenever accessing non-atomic variables.

Comment: @Barmar Right, but you explain incorrectly *why* you have to perform your own mutual exclusion. That answer has nothing to do with what happens or might happen on any particular hardware. It has everything to do with what the relevant standards say. My answer explains why.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify what threading model or standard you are using. But typical standards specify that it's undefined (or unspecified) behavior if you access an object in one thread while another thread is, or might be, modifying it.

You clearly do that with `y`. So there's no reason you should expect any particular outcome -- anything can happen. With some threading standards, it could crash or produce any result at all. With others, the final value of `y` is unspecified, but the code is otherwise guaranteed to do what you expect.

Do not get trapped into reasoning about what particular hardware (such as caches and registers) could or might do. That's entirely irrelevant to the answer to this question, as it for any question where you're writing code that follows a specification or standard. You cannot show that code is safe by not finding any way it can fail on some particular piece of hardware.

More importantly, you cannot show that code is unsafe by finding a way it can fail on some particular piece of hardware or platform. (This is why Barnar's answer is wrong.) We can always imagine ways code could execute such that it fails -- it's the job of the compiler *not* to compile code that way unless there's something wrong with the code itself.

For example, consider this code:

```
int i;

void foo()
{
    i++;
    bar();
    i++;
}
void bar()
{
    i++;
}
```

It would be totally invalid to argue that `foo` might only increment `i` twice because the value of `i` might be held in a register across the call to `bar`, losing `bar`'s change to `i`. Why? Because the compiler is only allowed to hold `i` in a register if it can prove that this will not affect the output of the code because the code follows all the standard's rules.

Reasoning about how things might happen such that the code fails only works if the code violates some rule. Otherwise, it's the compiler's job to make the code not fail, whatever that takes.

Barmar's argument applies to the code above just as well, but clearly that code cannot fail. So the argument is invalid. Either the code follows the rules or it does not. If it does not follow the rules, it's broken because it doesn't follow the rules. If it does follow the rules, then it's the job of the compiler and platform to make sure it doesn't somehow fail.

Presumably, the code is broken because it doesn't follow the rules for the threading platform or standard it was coded for. But we can't be sure because you haven't told us what that platform or standard is.

Comment: Unless you're tailoring your code to a specific platform and threading model, you have to allow for the possibility that threads may be interleaved in any possible order, and only a mutex can control the interaction between threads. So all I have to do is show a possible order that causes incorrect behavior of the shared variable.

Comment: @Barmar Sure, threads can interleave in any possible order, but it's still the compiler/platform's responsibility not to let that break any code that complies with the relevant standards. So the big question -- can interleaving break this or not -- cannot be answered with reference to particular platforms or hardware but only with reference to the relevant standards. As I show in my answer, you can make this exact same kind of argument to show that valid code can break.

Comment: Your example can't fail because C's sequence point requirements state the order that things must happen within a single thread. But when multithreading is involved, much of that is no longer in force. The only concession C makes to threading is the `sig_atomic_t` type and the `volatile` qualifier, which provide very minimal control.

Comment: @Barmar Exactly. If the standard says it must work, then it must work. If the standard doesn't say it must work, then it may not work. How it can or can't fail on actual or hypothetical hardware is irrelevant. The C standard says nothing about threading, so what controls here is the relevant threading standard. We don't know what that is, but most of them say it's undefined or unspecified behavior if an object is modified in one thread while another thread is, or might be, accessing it. So that's the key issue.

Comment: So how does that explain what happens in the real world to cause a particular result? That's the point of my answer: it shows a possible execution path, which is allowed by the standard, that gets the result he asked about.

Comment: @Barmar His issue is not what happens in the real world to cause a particular result. If it was, he would have specified the hardware and platform and the question would have been entirely different. It's why his expectation wasn't met, and that's because his expectation is unwarranted. He could have had precisely the same question even if the code had happened to do what he happened to expect it to do. (Though he says he gets the result `1` and `1`, I'm 99.8% certain he really means *if* he gets those results. Mostly because that's so unlikely to actually happen. I asked the OP to clarify.)

Comment: I interpret his question as asking "I expect to get result X, but I got result Y, how did that happen?". I showed how it's possible. Your answer doesn't really explain anything, it just says "You have to follow the standard, otherwise the results are undefined." That's a "because I said so" answer, like you would give a child who doesn't have enough experience to understand why you're telling them what to do. It doesn't explain why the standard says what it says.

Comment: @Barmar You have it precisely backwards. The standard doesn't say what it says because platforms do what they do. Compilers make code that makes the platform do what they do because the standard says what it says. Your explanation is just *wrong*. It's more complex than mine, yes, but the complexity obscures the simple point that you only get guarantees (and justified expectations) when you follow a standard that gives them to you. What platforms actually do it irrelevant because the compiler tells the platform what to do based on the standard.

Comment: You have it backwards. Standards are not written arbitrarily, they're based on real world experience. And when they have restrictions, they exist to solve problems that occur in concrete implementations. I've worked on a standards committee (ANSI X3J13 Common Lisp), and many decisions were made as concessions to the way implementation actually work. We could have (and sometimes did) decided to force implementations to change to meet our requirements, but mostly we codified and clarified what already existed as the least common denominator in popular implementations.

Comment: And multi-threading has been around for much longer than the C and POSIX standards. Their requirements are based on how typical multiprocessing systems actually work.